# Remove dots and zeros from hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an API that shows me the difference in hours between a country and another one.
It returns me, in Madrid, for example: '+02:00' but i need a single '+2'.

Is there any option?

```js
timezone = $.getJSON("https://www.worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Madrid.json", function(result){
          console.log(result.utc_offset); // Returns '+02:00'
        });
        timezone = timezone.replace(/\,/g,'');
        console.log(timezone);
```

Comment: What if it returns `-07:30`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey why should it return -7:30?

Comment: There are time zones that have half-hour offsets... https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oops, nice to know it. Luckily it does not happen with the countries i'm using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `slice` to get the hour, then `parseInt`

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Madrid.json", function(result) {
  let timezone = result.utc_offset
  let op = timezone[0] 
  timezone = parseInt(timezone.slice(1, 3));
  console.log(op + timezone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( https://gyazo.com/440a66c2b24e1757b1c5319ffdc57069

Comment: @Vander show me your piece of code that produced that error

Comment: Oops sorry i had a mistake in the code! It returns me the single number (2). Could it be possible to add a '+' in front of it?

Comment: @Vander sure, you keep an variable that store that sign. I updated the answer

Comment: @Vander no prob. glad that it could help